# Изменение ссылки

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! Есть ссылка, где адрес получаем из бд:

```
<a href="<?=$ap_category[0]['test'];?>/<?=$ap['test'];?>" class="btn btn-gradient btn-success">Подробнее</a>
```

Пример ссылки:

```
<a href="/category/news1" class="btn btn-gradient btn-success">Подробнее</a>
```

Необходимо перед `/category` добавить `news`. Пробовал делать так:

```
`<a href="/news/<?=$ap_category[0]['test'];?>/<?=$ap['test'];?>" class="btn btn-gradient btn-success">Подробнее</a>`
```

Сейчас ссылка в адресную строку вставляется, но не открывается сама новость(т.е. `../news1`). Вместо этого просто обновляется страница со всеми новостями. А если убрать `/` , `newscategory/news1` то тогда все работает, но этот вариант естественно не подходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а сервер в курсе, что у него такая структура каталогов? Или urlrewrite прописан?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov, страница на которую мы ссылаемся нет в дереве, а вся информация храниться в бд. Т.е. мы как бы ссылаемся на ту же страницу где находимся изначально

Comment: Это понятно. Но чтобы понять, что выводить, скрипту должны передаться параметры, выделенные из вашего url. Похоже, что изменение адреса ведет к "неправильным" параметрам и скрипт, не найдя соответствия, выводит дефолтную страницу со всеми новостями